# JQuery draggable - The opposide from connectToSortable

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

i can drop a draggable element into a sortable list.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ connectToSortable: '#myList' });
```

But how can i drop the element back?
The sortout event works only with a second list :/

kind regards
Peter

EDIT: working example 
http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/114/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look jQuery droppable

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable

So:

```
$('#droppable').droppable({
    drop: function() { //Do something }
});
```

Comment: It works, but the drop event start also when i sort the list ... here is an example http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/114/ Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: If it is just sorting that you are looking to do then sortable has a drag and drop sorting method so draggable and droppable may not be necessary! 

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#overview